# How to modify child Component content?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a Component like this:

```
<MyTimer props={+new Date()}>
    <span className="year" formatter="yyyy" />
    <span className="mon" formatter="mm" />
    <span className="day" formatter="dd" />
</MyTimer>
```

`MyTimer` is Component like this(I just ignore some other code):

```
render() {
    /**
      * this code may not work, I just do what I think.
     */

    return (<div>
         { this.props.children.map((child, i) => 
             // child.children=[util.date(child.formatter)])
             // set child.props.children as "util.date(child.formatter)"
         }
    </div>)
}
```

I want to change the content of `span` in component, which should result like this:

```
<span class="year">2016</span>
<span class="mon">07</span>
<span class="day">06</span>
```

So why do I need this, because I can change the child element type as I like:

```
<MyTimer props={+new Date()}>
    <div className="year" formatter="yyyy" />
    <span className="mon" formatter="mm" />
    <p className="day" formatter="dd" />
</MyTimer>
```

I just do not care about what the child element is, and also `className`.

Comment: what is `MyTimer`?  What is the `formatter` attribute?

Comment: @Brandon can I make you understand now? `formatter` is just a prop defined by myself so that I can format the string

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm having trouble understanding what you're asking. It looks like you already have child span components being returned. Do you want to modify those components?

Comment: @SArnab maybe this time?

Comment: I believe you are looking for cloneElement. https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#react.cloneelement. You can iterate through the children, and based on the formatter, change the content (inner child) of each cloned element. Then render those new ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

React has a feature called ["contexts"](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html), which allow a parent component to implicitly pass some data to children.

The actual formatting then can happen in a special "formatter" component. Resulting in something like this:

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import moment from 'moment';

class MyTimer extends Component {
    static childContextTypes = {
        date: PropTypes.object
    };

    // expose some props to children
    getChildContext() {
        return {
            date: this.props.date
        };
    }

    render() {
        return <div>{this.props.children}</div>;
    }
}

class TimerPart extends Component {
    // this is REQUIRED to receive the date from the parent
    static contextTypes = {
        date: PropTypes.object
    };

    render() {
        // use it like `this.context.date`
        return <span>{moment(this.context.date).format(this.props.format)}</span>;
    }
}

export default class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
          <MyTimer date={new Date()}>
            <TimerPart format="YYYY"/>
            <TimerPart format="MM"/>
            <TimerPart format="DD"/>
          </MyTimer>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: This! I was going to answer with exactly that — contexts are waaay better suited to deal with this than manipulating children.

Comment: I used the context from https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html but it's not the good implementation according to the doc :/

Comment: Yes context is a great feature of react (Redux uses that)

Comment: Edited the answer to expand a bit on the details, not just provide the code :) Hope you don't mind